# Displaying Order ID on checkout success page

Tags: opencart

I'll like the order id to be echoed on checkout success page of an opencart store. How do I do this? There are similar threads to this but I've tried the suggestions offered, didn't work for me. So I'm including links to the relevant codes here:

My catalog/controller/checkout/success.php is at http://pastebin.com/wPWau0Kv

My /template/common/success.tpl is at http://pastebin.com/5Jfpkur0

Thanks.

Comment: You've removed the code you shared from pastebin, making this question and @Pranav's answer absolutely useless to future readers. This is why questions are supposed to contain a [mcve] **in the question itself**.

Comment: I didn't actually removed it. It expired on pastebin. But they are standard opencart codes, that can be seen in any opencart download. If the downvotes are removed, I can paste them back with updated links.

Comment: Other way around. You need to edit the question to make it worth reopening. Voting isn't allowed on closed questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your `$this->session->data['order_id']`
there is ordrer_id stored so in controller you could passed with `$data['order_id']` you have to just echo in tpl so code maybe something like this:

In controller:

```
$data['activity_data']=$activity_data;
```

And In Template above `<div class="buttons">`:

```
echo $activity_data['order_id'];
```